# Flutter web HasValue changes while creating chat id

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

```
if (userID.hashCode <= peerID.hashCode) {
  groupChatId = '$userID-$peerID';
} else {
  groupChatId = '$peerID-$userID';
}
```

Both output are different from eachother:

```
android output:    Ra6KFj3FgtSVKWp8ZhZEOCf9wu93-9Bai5t5WC6We5QCYdn4VZLOQyuJ2
web output:        9Bai5t5WC6We5QCYdn4VZLOQyuJ2-Ra6KFj3FgtSVKWp8ZhZEOCf9wu93
```